# Can we have more-consistent flag colors within a site?

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, flags, design, moderator-tools

The topbar now uses blue for flag counts across all sites:

[image: topbar]

This adds a *third* color representing flags to the mix.  On Mi Yodeya and Writers (beta), the only ones where I have direct knowledge, the moderator history tab has always used yellow -- for the total, the number in the tab, and the per-moderator numbers, such as:

[image: mod history]

But this indicator on another page (mods know which one I'm talking about) has always been *orange*:

[image: mod-menu]

<s>Request #1: Can we at *least* make the two site-specific flag colors match?  Both pages have the same page background; any color that works on one works on the other.  (Yellow is currently used for something else in the second page; you'd need to change that.)  This request applies to both of the sites where I'm a mod (and, by implication, all beta sites), and probably many others, so I'm asking here rather than on per-site metas.</s>  Edit: these have now been made consistent (though the specific choices could use some further refinement for legibility):

[image: updated screen shot]

Request #2: is it feasible to use the new blue everywhere?  It works well on light and dark backgrounds, but would have poor contrast on a site whose page background is in the medium-to-dark-blue range.  Do we have sites like that?  (I have not visited all graduated sites.)  It might also be more legible than white on orange.

Consistency across all sites was important enough to for the topbar; I suggest that consistency *within* a site is also important.